# LINQ lambda OrderByDescending on group by key.count() returning list of string of group by key for chart legend sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

Trying to sort the legend of a pie chart in MVC 4 C#.  The chart shows number of products sold by their item numbers.  In the legend I want to display the item number, then number sold, then the percent sold and have this ordered by number sold descending.

I've gotten the "Y" values (# sold) to order correctly but in trying to order the "X" values they end up jumbled and don't match their proper "Y" values.

It appears to me like I should just have to group the data by item number, then select the data by anonymous type of item number and count of item number, then order by descending based on the item number count, then select again this time only taking a list string of the item numbers now in the correct order.

There is a reasonable chance the above is working fine and the problem more lies with my near complete lack of understanding of how the `DataBindXY` method works in charting.

Code:

```
var data = srv.GetTSMMetricData(Mode, Territories, selectedTerritory).GroupBy(x => x.ItemNumber).ToList();

var xValues = data.Select(x => x.Key).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).ToList();

mySeries.Points.DataBindXY(xValues, data.Select(x => x.Count()).OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList());
```

Any help or nudge in the right direction would be awesome.  Let me know if there is anything else I can post up that might be missing.

Thanks.

Edit: Forgot I was trying to use anonymous type in previous version of the above code..

```
var xValues = data.Select(x => new { Item = x.Key, Count = x.Key.Count() }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).ToList();

mySeries.Points.DataBindXY(xValues.Select(x => x.Item).ToList(), data.Select(x => x.Count()).OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList());
```

Edit 2: Example of current result (top 5 legend entries)..

```
ItemNumber - # Sold - % Sold ----- Correct ItemNumber for # Sold
-------------------------------------------------------------
8500         42       (20.79)%     PRS
JOL          19       (9.41)%      JOL
280          18       (8.91)%      ENV
171          13       (6.44)%      AMR
172          12       (5.94)%      GRD

Note: 38 rows of total results
```

The results have all the correct ItemNumbers for the query and all the # Sold but is not matching the ItemNumbers to the correct # Sold.  I can re-write the code so that the ItemNumbers and # Sold match up but only order it by ItemNumber and I really want to order it by # Sold.  Hopefully this makes it more clear what the problem is and what I'd like to see happen.

Comment: Well, `Key` is the common value of the grouped objects' `ItemNumber` property - not sure why you'd call `Count()`...

Comment: As far as I understand it the Key would be the ItemNumbers and the Count of Key would be how many of each ItemNumber was grouped, this makes up the X and Y values used to graph the pie chart.  As I said though I'm brand new to charting so I could have that wrong.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what result you're expecting or what the original data looks like.  Can you add a small example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that by sorting twice you mix up the order of the keys and the values.

Make sure that you first create a list of pairs that is sorted correctly:

```
var data = srv.GetTSMMetricData(Mode, Territories, selectedTerritory)
           .GroupBy(x => x.ItemNumber)
           .Select( x => new
                        {
                            ItemNumber = x.Key,
                            Count = x.Count()
                        } )
           .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
           .ToList();
```

Then do the binding:

```
mySeries.Points.DataBindXY(data.Select(x => x.ItemNumber)
                          ,data.Select(x => x.Count));
```

Comment: I tried something similar to this and the result was very strange.  Copy/Paste of what you have gives me a "NotImplementedException" error.  Just had to add a .ToList() to the X and Y value being passed into the DataBindXY method.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`GroupBy` returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey,TEntity>`

To count the number of objects in each grouping:

```
srv.GetTSMMetricData(Mode, Territories, selectedTerritory)
    .GroupBy(x => x.ItemNumber)
    .Select( x => new
        {
            ItemNumber = x.Key,
            Count = x.Count()
        } );
```